# Xcode Launch application and brint to front NSWorkspace

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, launch

I have the following code to launch Address Book, now that works well, but is there a way I could launch this infront of the running application?

```
[[NSWorkspace sharedWorkspace] openFile:@"/Applications/Address Book.app" withApplication:nil];
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try the NSWorkspace method:

```
- (NSRunningApplication *)launchApplicationAtURL:(NSURL *)url options:(NSWorkspaceLaunchOptions)options configuration:(NSDictionary *)configuration error:(NSError **)error
```

Also note you should use `URLForApplicationWithBundleIdentifier:` rather than a fixed path. This will work even if Address Book.app is moved in a future version of OS X, or the user moves it to a different folder.

Comment: Good point. For backwards compatibility there's also _launchAppWithBundleIdentifier:options:additionalEventParamDescriptor:launchIdentifier:_ which should accomplish the same thing (it just doesn't return helpful information about the process).

Answer (score 1):

You could even use `[[NSWorkspace sharedWorkspace] launchApplication: @"Address Book"]`.